# Positioning rotated element on right side of page

Tags: css, rotation

[JSBin demo here.](http://jsbin.com/odevoh/4/edit)
How can I position a `div` rotated 90 degrees on the right edge of the page, centered vertically? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-20px; /* height */
    right:-200px; /* width */
} ​ ​​
```

Comment: Sorry, in my actual code the width is variable and can't be known. I got it working by using Javascript. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    div{
vertical-align:middle;
    float:right;
    /* FF Chrome Opera etc */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* IE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }
```

Check [this](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html), may help you a bit.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't seem to work for me. Thanks for your help!